# i want to transfer file from linux to windows from root using scp/pscp commands, but iam getting access denied error

Tags: scp

i want to transfer a text file from Linux (centos) to windows using scp/pscp commands from root, but I am getting access denied error when executing scp -r {file name} user@ip:/

Comment: I guess you need to provide the user's password on the windows server

Comment: can u tell me the exact command

Comment: `scp <source file> <user>@<address>:<destination>`. You will be asked for the password on the command line. Maybe the `-r` option is the problem since that one expects a source directory.

Comment: I am getting port 22:connection refused lost connection error. please help

Comment: This means there's no ssh (the protocol on which scp is based) server active on your windows server.